# Duplicate entries in update-alternatives

Tags: vim, update-alternatives

I have two entries for vim when I input `sudo update-alternatives --config editor`

```
  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/local/bin/vim   100       auto mode
  1            /bin/ed             -100       manual mode
  2            /bin/nano            40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    10        manual mode
  4            /usr/local/bin/vim   100       manual mode

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/local/bin/vim   100       auto mode
  1            /bin/ed             -100       manual mode
* 2            /bin/nano            40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    10        manual mode
  4            /usr/local/bin/vim   100       manual mode
```

Why does this happen and how can I remove it?

Comment: That's normal. Try choosing `/bin/nano` instead and then checking for dups.

Comment: That does not change the result. Please see it in the question.

Comment: Notice that one alternative is set to manual and the other to auto, they are different (in that sense): read `man update-alternatives`.

Answer (score 3):

You have 4 alternatives declared for `editor`, corresponding to the lines numbered 1 to 4. The line numbered 0 always lists the alternative with the highest priority, which is the one that `update-alternatives --auto` would set.

If you select 0 at this menu, this puts the alternative into automatic mode, so if a higher-priority alternative appears, it will become selected instead. If you select 4, then `/usr/local/bin/vim` will remain selected no matter what else you install.

The entry for `/usr/local/bin/vim` must have been declared manually, since no Ubuntu package includes anything under `/usr/local`. If you want to remove it from the selection, run `sudo update-alternatives --remove editor /usr/local/bin/vim`; the group will be switch back to automatic mode (so `/bin/nano` will become choice 0 and selected).